# function template overload resolution with user defined conversion operator

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, language-lawyer

What is the correct output for following code according to C++11 standard?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename X>
class A
{
public: 
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A::A" << std::endl;
    }
    A(const A<X>&)
    {
        std::cout << "A::A(const A<X>&)" << std::endl;
    }
    A<X>& operator = (const A<X>&)
    {
        std::cout << "A::opeartor =(conat A&)" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

void* GetData()
{
    // return data based on some condition
    static A<int> a;
    return &a;
}

class P
{

public:
    template <typename T>
    operator T&()
    {
        void* pData = GetData();             
        std::cout << "P::operator T&()" << std::endl;
        return *(reinterpret_cast<T*>(pData));
    }

    operator A<int>()
    {
        std::cout << "P::opeartor A<int>" << std::endl;
        return A<int>();
    }
};

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/)
{
    P objP;
    A<int> objA = objP; // case 1
    objA = objP; // case 2
    return 0;
}
```

clang and gcc produce following output.

```
P::opeartor A<int>
A::A
A::A
P::operator T&()
A::opeartor =(conat A&)
```

VS 2015 generates output as shown below.

```
A::A
P::operator T&()
A::A(const A<X>&)
P::operator T&()
A::opeartor =(conat A&)
```

**Case 1**

VS2015 picks template version where as gcc and clang picks non template version.

**Case 2**

All three compilers pick template version.

How can we explain this behavior with reference to C++ 11 standard?

Comment: When in doubt, assume VS doesn't comply. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSVC is wrong. The behavior here depends on whether the destination type is a reference type, which affects the set of candidate functions.

- In copy-initialization of an object (`A<int> objA = objP;`), the applicable rules in [[dcl.init]/17](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17) says that the destination type is `A<int>` and the candidate set is governed by [[over.match.copy]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.copy), under whose rules that it includes both conversion functions; they are tied, and the template/non-template tiebreaker selects the non-template.
- In initializing a reference `const A<int>&` (the parameter of `operator=`), [[dcl.init.ref]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5) applies, which says that you first do overload resolution with a candidate set specified by [[over.match.ref]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.ref), which, when initializing an lvalue reference to object, includes only conversion function returning references.

  Thus in this case the only candidate is the template; it proves viable and is selected. The non-template isn't even considered.

This also means that `A<int> objA(objP);` will use the template, because there you do overload resolution on the constructors of `A<int>`, and will be trying to initialize the `const A<int>&` parameter of `A<int>`'s copy constructor.

Comment: To point out one detail: When initializing a reference, conversion functions that make the reference bind *directly* are preferred. That is, if the conversion function template is not present, then `operator A<int>` is chosen. It is a two-step procedure between direct/indirect binding and overload resolution.

Comment: (Though I don't quite know if the second but last bullet point *"If T1 or T2 is a class type [...]"* is considered direct binding.)